# How to add default namespace to (de)serialized XML via JMS/Serializer?

Tags: php, xml, laravel, serialization, jms-serializer

I am using JMS/Serializer (in Laravel). I have generated *.yml files and *.php classes for my serializer. There are xml_root_name and xml_root_namespace defined in my yml file:

```
App\Test\MyApp\PurchaseOrder:
   xml_root_name: PurchaseOrder
   xml_root_namespace: http::/tempuri.org/Schema.xsd
```

Now when I try to deserialize my XML, the behavior differs, depending on whether there is namespace definition in my XML root element or not.

```
<?xml version="1.0!>
<PurchaseOrder OrderDate="2018-01-01" xmlns="http::/tempuri.org/Schema.xsd">
  ...
</PurchaseOrder>
```

deserializes nicely to PurchaseOrder Object and subsequent objects. However without namespace definition in the root

```
<?xml version="1.0!>
<PurchaseOrder OrderDate="2018-01-01">
  ...
</PurchaseOrder>
```

the deserialization is only partial (i.e only OrderDate is deserialized from XML, but rest of the elements are not).

Related problem appears when I try do serialize my own object: the resulting XML has all the data, but the root element has no namespace defined. I.e the output is:

```
<?xml version="1.0!>
<PurchaseOrder OrderDate="2018-01-01">
  ...
</PurchaseOrder>
```

The set-up for serializer is:

```
$builder = SerializerBuilder::create();
$builder->addMetadataDir('metadata', 'App\Test\MyApp\PurchaseOrder');
$builder->configureHandlers(function(HandlerRegistryInterface $handler) use ($builder) {
  $builder->addDefaultHandlers();
  $handler->registerSubscribingHandler(new XmlSchemaDateHandler());
});
$serializer = $builder->build();
...
$object = $serializer->deserialize($xml, 'App\Test\MyApp\PurchaseOrder', 'xml');
```

How do I apply default namespace(s) in the JMS/Serializer, so if I recieve XML without namespace definition, I would still able to parse and deserialize this file? Also, how to apply namespace to root element, when I am serializing my object?